# BQ Aquaris M10 will not detect MS Designer keyboard or mouse

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, tablet

Brand new M10, done OTA upgrade. Trying to get it work with bluetooth keyboard and mouse.. Nothing detected in bluetooth manager when they in pairing mode. Keyboard and mouse both detcted by my Nexus 5 and 7. M10 detects the 5 and 7, just not keyboard or mouse.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I saw a similar question somewhere, and it was suggested that it might have to do with some MS keyboards and mouses using BLE (Bluetooth Smart).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the Bluetooth facility of the phablet is restricted to connecting just one single device. As a result, you can connect either a BT keyboard or else a BT mouse. Another viable BT solution would be to connect one of those fancy BT keyboards with an integrated touchpad which figures as a single device.

Comment: -1 as the OP states that the M10 does not detect any of the devices.